# C# - Backgroundworker and REST service

Tags: c#, rest, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I have a webservice that call a class with backgroundworker and when i return a status 200, i receive this exception in my REST client:

```
An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.
```

I've implemented my service this way:

```
    [Route("/service")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage generate(String value)
    {           
        Service service = new Service();
        service.Execute();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);          
    }
```

And here is my class with backgroundworker:

```
public class Service
{

    private BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();


    public void Execute(Client client)
    {
        worker = new BackgroundWorker
        {
            WorkerReportsProgress = true,
            WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
        };

        worker.DoWork += (obj, e) => GenerateContent(client);
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (obj, e) => GenerationCompleted(client.Token);


        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void GenerateContent(Client client)
    {
       //doStuff
    }


    private void GenerationCompleted(String token)
    {
        // TODO 
        Console.WriteLine("Finished");

    }
}
```

What's wrong with this implementation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `Execute` method will return immediately after starting the `BackgroundWorker` (rather than waiting until `GenerateContent` and `GenerationCompleted` have run).  So your service will return an HTTP 200 result to the client while `GenerateContent` is still working.

Comment: How can i avoid this problem? Wait the execution before return HTTP 200?

Comment: Hm, I was going to recommend getting rid of the threading/background work entirely.  If you have to tie up the `generate` thread waiting on the `BackgroundWorker` (or another thread that you create manually), you're not gaining anything from the threading and might as well put the body of `GenerateContent` inline in `generate`.